# how to start key listener at the start of program in java

Tags: java

So I have three labels and I added a mouse clicked listener on them. If I clicked the label, the value inside the label will change. Now, I want to add a key press listener. When I press letter a for example, I want my label1 to change also its value. I already made a keyeventlistener for that but it doesn't do what I want.

```
private void secondKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {    
    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){    
        int number = Integer.parseInt(second.getText());
        number = number + 1;
        String number1 = String.valueOf(number);
        first.setText(number1);
    }
}
```

My program has 3 buttons so when I start my program, the first button is highlighted so I guess, that's the place where I should do an event listener? Is there anyway that I can start adding key event listener on the very start of my program?

Comment: Why is it `secondKeyPressed`? make it `keyPressed`

Comment: If you can provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) it'd be easier to help you. There are many ways to do this but without your code we can't determine which one is the best to fit your use.

Comment: Use the key bindings API instead

Comment: You're missing some brackets there, is that `if` to a single line intentional?